# Extracting text in two dimensional array from a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I've a text file in linux with following text

```
;ip address    hostname     put-location      alt-put-location                tftpserver
192.168.1.1    r01-lab1-net /mnt/nas1/fgbu/   /opt/fgbu/devicebackup          192.168.1.254
192.168.1.2    r01-lab2-net /mnt/nas2/fgbu/   /opt/fgbu/backup                192.168.1.222
...
...
```

Now I want to extract each value in an array for later use. for example if i run following command

```
echo arry[2][2]
```

it should give output like following:

```
r01-lab2-net
```

one way is to use for loop but i fail to understand how will i move to next line. also please let me know if there is any better way using awk. or any other way to get these values in bash.

Comment: Can you use a scripting language like Python?

Comment: no. rest of my program is using bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash doesn't support 2 dimensional arrays, but you can use other bash utilities.

For ex. awk has support for 2 dimensional array. Read more about it here: http://porthos.ist.utl.pt/docs/gawk/gawk_9.html#SEC128

Comment: What if i run my program as " read first line and do some actions, read 2nd line and then same actions, read 3rd line"... can it be done this way?

Comment: Yes you can read the file line by line and process each line.